# When to use the preposition “zu” together with “passen”

Tags: preposition, verb-usage

Another confusing word + preposition combination to me, please could someone clarify the usage of:

> Das passt mir sehr gut

or

> Das passt zu mir sehr gut?
>
> Wir passen zueinander sehr gut

or

> Wir passen miteinander sehr gut

Comment: Does this link answer your question? http://www.dwds.de/?view=10&qu=passen

Comment: Note that ‘wir passen miteinander’ is not an idiomatic sentence. If anything, you probably to contrast ‘wir passen *einander* sehr gut’.

Comment: Nur Fußballer beim Doppelpass können sagen 'Wir passen miteinander sehr gut'. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the usages of *passen* (without complement), *jemandem passen* (which has multiple, only mildly related meanings) and *zu jemandem/etwas passen.*

*Passen* without complement means *to fit* in the sense of a key fitting into a keyhole.

> Dieser Schlüssel passt.
>
> »Weltmacht mit drei Buchstaben?« »Ich« »Oh ja, das passt.« (when solving a crossword puzzle.)

It can also be used in the sense of *being okay,* although that has overlap with *jemandem passen:*

> Morgen um zwölf? Das passt (mir).

(There are more meanings, but they are irrelevant in most contexts.)

*Jemandem passen* is usually only applied to clothing or accessories and (again) means *to fit* in the sense of *being neither too big nor too small.*

> Dieser Pullover passt mir nicht. Ich brauche eine Größe kleiner.

Of course, to add to the confusion, the dative object can be dropped if it is clear:

> Die Schuhe passen besser.

However, see above on the also possible meaning of *being okay.*

Finally, *zu jemandem/etwas passen* means *to match/to suit something else.*

> Die Farbe dieser Kette passt nicht zu meinem Lidschatten!
>
> Der Schirm passt zu mir! Ich mag alles mit Hunden.
>
> Wir zwei passen gut zueinander. Wir denken ähnlich und lachen über die gleichen Witze.

Note that this answer only covers the meanings 1–3 as given [by the Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/passen).

Comment: +1 for the German usage, but I think that “to fit to” does not exist in that sense.

Comment: @CarstenS Improved translation?

Comment: Ich mag alles mit Hunden? :-/ i did't understand, let me search a little bit :-))

Comment: This "ich mag alles mit Hunden" is an idiom, or realy do you have a lot of dogs? Could you please broader?

Comment: @user1474062 ‘Ich mag alles mit Hunden’ → *I like everything with dogs* in context to be understood as *I like everything that has dogs on it* so the umbrella would be one decorated with dogs.